# Training CNN do all ground truths need to be positively identified?

Tags: deep-learning

Some background:

- I'm collecting data for an object detection CNN (something along the lines of SSD/YOLO)
- It's classifying one type of object into many classes
- These objects often appear clustered in large (10-30 ) groups

When creating the bounding box labels for the objects in each image, is it okay to only label say half of the objects present? Are there any consequences to this other than needing more data?

Answer (score 0):

All positives must be annotated for both train & test images.

If not annotated, its kind of a paradox for the network. The network will still try to learn features from the annotated objects. But learning will be incomplete an it will not converge properly.